# Flex Box Grid container / Ionic full screen View Css

Tags: css, grid, ionic-framework, flexbox

After reading a lot of article, tutorials and so many other things, I'm stuck with something that makes me crazy.

Here is what I'm trying to do with flex container:

[Picture Css flexbox grid here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctzspsz56moon1k/grid.jpg?dl=0)

I think I have missed something with flex grid. It's impossible for me to have correct CSS to get this picture to render.

Can you help me with a little something just for the beginning?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I confess I do not know the Ionic framework but here' how it can be done using `flexbox`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-1000-600-9.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
main {
  flex-basis: 80%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
}
main .item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid gold;
  margin: 5px;
}
footer {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
footer .item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <main>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. With your flex css and ionic framework here is what i have :

[preview here : ionic strange behavior](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqqvwklr9b6b77g/rendu_css1.PNG?dl=0)

Thank you very for this help, I appreciate :-)

```css
.scroll {
height: 100%;
}
.page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-1000-600-9.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
main {
    flex-basis: 80%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 5px;
}
main .item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 2px solid gold;
    margin: 5px;
}
footer {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 5px;
}
footer .item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ion-view title="Accueil" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-content scroll="false" >
        <ion-content>
            <div class="page">
                <main>
                    <div class="item"></div>
                    <div class="item"></div>
                </main>
                <footer>
                    <div class="item"></div>
                    <div class="item"></div>
                </footer>
            </div>
            
        </ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: You are very welcome. It's expected (but not required) that if an answer helped you to upvote it &/or accept it as the answer.